# getting error mapping over document data flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

i am trying to get a list of data from my firebase storage i have tried to get the data by mapping over `snapshot.data.documents` and then converting it to a list by:

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> items = snapshot.data.documents;
              var messages =
                items.map((i) => ChatMessage.fromJson(i.data)).toList();
```

however i am getting the following error

> The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

is there some other way to retrieve/format? thanks.

Comment: Can you post content of `ChatMessage`? Also it should `i.data()` instead of `i.data`.

Comment: @TirthPatel thanks for the quick reply, i have changed i.data to i.data(), but i get another error from that: 
```
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("name")
```

ChatMessage is a member of the package "dash_chat",which i am using for my app

Comment: I'm not sure about `i.data()`. What does `ChatMessage.fromJson` expect (datatype)?

Comment: @TirthPatel i found this snippet : 

`ChatMessage ChatMessage.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json)`

Comment: Try changing it to `Map<String, dynamic> json`

Comment: @TirthPatel that is inside the package, i dont think it is reasonable to change the package code itself...is there a way to correct it from the function call itself(ChatMessage.fromJson(i.data))?

Comment: Oh! I didn't know it was part of the package! I assumed it would be a model or helper.

Comment: @TirthPatel yep :) sorry for not stating that earlier